# Angular dependency issue

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

HTML file:

```
<div class="header" ng-controller='HomeCtrl as homeCtrl'>
    <div class="panel-header container">
      <h1>UkrBook</h1>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">
        <li ng-class="{active: homeCtrl.isSelected(1)}"><a href ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(1, 'home')">Головна</a></li>
        <li ng-hide="" ng-class="{active: homeCtrl.isSelected(2)}"><a href ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(2, 'login')">Увійдіть</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: homeCtrl.isSelected(3)}"><a href ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(3, 'register')">Реєстрація</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: homeCtrl.isSelected(4)}"><a href ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(4, 'about')">Про нас</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: homeCtrl.isSelected(5)}"><a href ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(5, 'profile')">Профіль</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: homeCtrl.isSelected(6)}"><a href ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(6, 'home', Auth.logout())">Вийти</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller piece:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($state, Auth) {
    var homeCtrl = this;
    homeCtrl.tab = 1;
    homeCtrl.logout = Auth.logout;

    homeCtrl.selectTab = function(setTab, state, callback) {
      homeCtrl.tab = setTab;
      $state.go(state).then(callback),
        function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        };

    };
```

Auth service:

```
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth, FirebaseUrl, $state) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl);
    var Auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    Auth.logout = function(){
      ref.unauth().then(function(){
        console.log('Logged out');
        $state.go('home');
      }, function(error){
        authCtrl.error = error;
      });
    };

    return Auth;
```

The problem is following: `Auth.logout` method from HTML file can't be loaded, though I'm using `HomeCtrl` as a controller, which has DI `Auth` factory. 
So, to make it clear, this one won't work:

`ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(6, 'home', Auth.logout())"`

I have to add `homeCtrl.logout = Auth.logout;` to the `HomeCtrl` and call `homeCtrl.logout` in my HTML file.

Could someone please explain to me, why can't I do so and is it a proper way of injecting services? Also I would appreciate some good articles with examples about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a view, you only have access to controller data, through $scope. You can't access service methods.

The way you do inject service is correct.

For a good documentation about $scope, see angularjs official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope,

and for a good explanation of DI, see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection

Comment: Thanks. So, this is the only way how I can access? All the time reassigning method in the controller?

Comment: Yes. Usually you will not need all your services methods in your views, but a small fraction of them, or a combination of them...

Answer (score 1):

While injecting the 'Auth' factory into your controller makes it available to call within your controller, it does not make it available to the view.  The step that you took, homeCtrl.logout = Auth.logout exposes the Auth.logout function to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
<li ng-class="{active: homeCtrl.isSelected(6)}"><a href ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(6, 'home', Auth.logout())">Вийти</a></li>
```

by

```
<li ng-class="{active: homeCtrl.isSelected(6)}"><a href ng-click="homeCtrl.selectTab(6, 'home', homeCtrl.logout())">Вийти</a></li>
```

and in controller.

```
homeCtrl.logout = function() { Auth.logout() };
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Poiting direclty to Auth.logout is rather a bad idea, he should rewrite his homeCtrl.logout to be homeCtrl.logout = function(){Auth.logout()};

Comment: Why should I wrap it into a function?

Comment: Yes. It should lose its factory context. @Walfrat Thanks. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
homeCtrl.logout = Auth.logout;
```

do:

```
homeCtrl.logout = function() { Auth.logout() };
```

You are losing context to the internal closure of the Auth constructor when you bind it directly to your controller this way.